# Smartsheet API error when using curl to update column picklist values

Tags: php, curl, smartsheet-api

Good Morning,
I'm looking for a way to update the dropdown values in a column in my Smartsheet. Going off the Smartsheet API 2.0, I managed to come up with the following code to use with curl, but I'm getting the following error when running it in CMD.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/7654838910642052/columns/4 -H "Authorization: Bearer 6cn0otb4tdjueqzuflgnkzff17" -X PUT -d '{"title":"Weekend Date","index":4, "type" : "PICKLIST", "options" :["31-OCT-2015"]}' -k
```

The error message I get from CMD, is as follows:

```
C:\New>curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/7654838910642052/columns/4 -H "Authorization: Bearer 5cn0otb4tdjueqzuflgnkzff17" -X PUT -d '{"title"
:"Weekend Date","index":4, "type" : "PICKLIST", "options" :["31-OCT-2015"]}' -k
{"errorCode":1124,"message":"Invalid Content-Type header. Media type not supported."}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: type; Host not found
¶hA▓╔ôÒ±$═»ù0♠~¡lk§☺▄ÜQ­K¡^ Õf ƒîa♀ÛæçÂ"õ8Ê╝±↕åÊJcurl: (6) Could not resolve host: PICKLIST,; Host not found
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: options; Host not found
curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 3
```

Would appreciate any help I can get!!! This error is really annoying, and I have spent a good few hours trying to fix it.

** Note that I have changed the access token for security reasons, but the token I am using is definitely valid **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joseph suggested in his answer, you'll certainly want to verify that the value you're specifying for {columnId} in the URL is valid.  However, the error you're getting is likely unrelated to that issue.

What's likely happening is that cURL is automatically setting the Content-Type header for you to the value "application/x-www-form-urlcoded" -- which is not a valid content type for this request to Smartsheet.  You can resolve this error by simply setting the Content-Type header yourself in the request (i.e., add this: `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` to the request).

For example, my request to update the picklist options for a column such that the only option is "31-OCT-2015" looks like this:

```
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}/columns/{columnId} -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d "{\"type\":\"PICKLIST\", \"options\":[\"31-OCT-2015\"]}" -k
```

Note that to update picklist options, the only attributes I need to set in the JSON are `type` and `options`.  Also note that I used (escaped) double quotes in the JSON instead of single quotes -- you may or may not need to do this (depending on your platform).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful post Kim. I'm now getting an error that looks like this `{"errorCode":1006,"message":"Not Found"}`   What does this mean?

Comment: The Not found error generally means that the URL is incorrect in some way. I'd suggest that you verify that the Sheet ID and Column ID are correct in the URL. Please note that column index (ex "4") is not the column ID -- column ID will be a long guid that looks similar to sheet ID.  You can execute a "Get Columns" API request for that sheet (GET /sheets/{sheetid}/columns) to see the column IDs).

Comment: Thanks Kim!!! It worked.... I didn't realise the Column ID was a Guid - I was confusing Index with Column ID. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path you're using may be incorrect. I can see there's a "4" included in the path where the Column ID should be. For updating Column(s), you'd use the following path:

> curl
>   https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}/columns/{columnId}

You can find the API reference [here](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#update-column).